# Unable to makemigrations with PostgreSQL setup

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to setup PostgreSQL locally on my computer, but when I try to initially set up my Django application with it using `python manage.py makemigrations`, I am given this warning:

```
RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration 
history performed for database connection 'default': fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

My database table in my `settings.py` is as follows:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': os.environ.get("DB_NAME"),
    'USER': os.environ.get("DB_USER"),
    'PASSWORD': os.environ.get("DB_PASSWORD"),
    'HOST': os.environ.get("DB_HOST"),
    'PORT': os.environ.get("DB_PORT"),
  }
}
```

My `.env` file is located in the same directory as my `manage.py` file:

```
DB_NAME=Smash
DB_PASSWORD=root
DB_USER=SmashDatabase
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432

DEBUG=1
```

I tried following [this link's instructions](https://hinty.io/ivictbor/fix-django-db-utils-operationalerror-fe-sendauth-no-password-supplied/) but none of the offered solutions fixed the problem. I don't know what is wrong or what causes this issue.

Comment: Are you using `django-environ`? If not, how is the .env file propagated into the Django environment?

Comment: Pretty straight forward, a password is not being supplied for a connection that needs one. Have you correctly setup `python-dotenv` per instructions [here](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/)?

Comment: I was under the impression that as long as the .env was in the same directory it would share the same environment. If that's not the case how do people use ``os.environ.get``?

Comment: `os.environ.get` will fetch variables that have been set in an environment from the shell or  added via  `os.putenv()`. `.env` is a file based method of overriding the previous. In order to use it you need to do some setup in your application. I have done that using `python-dotenv`. Then there is the other suggestion [django-environ](https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Are you using either or none?

Comment: I'm using django-environ now, but I was using neither of them prior. When I was looking up ``os.environ.get``, I never saw anything about needing to set up anything in the shell, how would I do that for future reference?

Comment: It depends on the OS and its shell and whether you want it just for a session or everytime you use the shell. There are plenty of tutorials online that can step you through it.  You can also use `os.environ` to set env variables, though that is session specific if I remember correctly. Also I was wrong previously,  variables created by `putenv()` will not be see in `os.environ`. See [putenv](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.putenv).